# Java says: **ERROR**: Unable to access javafile

Tags: java, actionscript-3

*[(It's sad this question has already been asked.)]*

I've the batchfile `D:\Hydroper\Projects\Java\ASC\bin\asc.cmd` that executes a JAR file `.\target\asc-1.jar` in the same directory. Absolute path: `D:\Hydroper\Projects\Java\ASC\bin\target\asc-1.jar`.

However, when I execute my batchfile, I get the Unable to access jarfile error:

```
asc -strict Main.as
```

but my JAR is there. Even adding a `.jar` or executing with admin privileges the error persists. It was automatically built with Maven.

Here my batch:

```
java -jar "D:\Hydroper\Projects\Java\ASC\bin\target\asc-1" %*
```

It works when I do `java -jar ... args` manually in the command-line, but I don't like that. I prefer aliasing that command.

**ClassPath**

I've instead also tried something like:

```
java macromedia.asc.embedding.Main "%*"
```

It works fine, but ASC doesn't. `asc -help` works fine, but `asc -help Main.as` says my AS file cannot be found, but I'm in the right directory.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do the below:-

```
cd D:\Hydroper\Projects\Java\ASC\bin
```

copy the `asc.cmd` file to `bin` folder and modify the batch file like below

```
 java -jar target\asc-1.jar
```

First execute the above command from command prompt first before executing the same from batch file like below:-

```
cd D:\Hydroper\Projects\Java\ASC\bin
java -jar target\asc-1.jar
```

When we use a batch file or shell script to run a java application do it like below:-

in your batch file

```
CP="C:\lib\example1.jar;C:\lib\example2.jar;D:\Hydroper\Projects\Java\ASC\bin\target\asc-1.jar"

java -cp %CP% com.your.java.class.MyExample
```

Comment: ASC is alrealdy in bin, but now I realised I forgot Macromedia folder before `\ASC\`, so I upvote for your help. Well, it works fine in command-line, but in batchfile, ASC still fails saying my Main.as cannot be found. I'm not sure why! P.S.: relative path doesn't work, that's why I had to switch using a fully-specified path with D:\.

Comment: Did you run asc.cmd from bin or you are running it like D:\Hydroper\Projects\Java\ASC\bin\asc.cmd? Run it in bin like ./asc.cmd

Comment: I run it from bin using a absolute path with D:\ (absolute due to the horrible java.exe, though...). However, my Main.as is in C:\Users\X\Documents\Main.as, even though asc.cmd (my batchfile) executes fine there. I've many times tried a relative path, but it doesn't really work; weird, strange.

Comment: To resume: The current error happens in ASC. I'm not sure if it's taking my current working directory. However, it worked earlier. That's weird...

Comment: use a class path variable and try. In your batch file first set class path for all the jars in a variable and in java -cp %CP%

Comment: Well, cp would for sure be cd, though. CP is code page, but CD is current directory...

Comment: @Hydroper, I have modified my answer. Try with the last option

Comment: Thank you, but I've already tried the class path solution. So, in your example, there's no need to define ClassPath in the environment. I think I need to open a new question in this case.